# How to get application path in Red5 (absolute and relative)

Tags: java, red5

I made a application and placed it in webapps as new folder, say appcustom.
There are some text files that I want to read.
How do I generically read rather than hardcoding the path?

Currently I am using something like this:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("webapps/appcustom/<<textfilename>>"); // read a file
```

How do I make it generic? Because tomorrow I may want to change the application folder name to "custApp" or something else.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few system properties that you can use in Red5, I would use this block if I were attempting to read a resource from a generic application class:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(String.format("%s/%s/%s", System.getProperty("red5.webapp.root"), appName, fileName));
```

The application name (ex: oflaDemo) and your file name would need to be supplied.

From an ApplicationAdapter you have access to a "usable" application name:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(String.format("%s/%s/%s", System.getProperty("red5.webapp.root"), getScope().getName(), fileName));
```

From an Servlet you have access to a full path:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(String.format("%s/%s", getServletContext().getRealPath("/"), fileName));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Properties props = new Properties();
   // Looks for the file 'database.properties' in {TOMCAT_HOME}\webapps\{RED5_HOME}\WEB-INF\
   FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("red5.config_root") + "/database.properties");
   props.load(in);
```

I found this way very helpfull in reading any file.

[Here is the link of full example](http://www.red5tutorials.net/index.php/Tutorials%3aMySQL_and_Red5)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this [Streaming_from_custom_directories](http://www.red5tutorials.net/index.php/Tutorials%3aStreaming_from_custom_directories)